# React.js synchronity problem with hooks. Connect Four game move

Tags: reactjs

I am currently building a connect-four game based on react.js. It has the following semantic:
The game has 3 state variables: `grid`(play field), `pNext`(boolean if human is next), `gameState`(is game won, lost, or running?)

1. Human will click on column and `onclick` event `handleClick(i)` is triggered with the column index. It checks the `gameState` and will call the `makeMove(i)` function to make the players move. Now is the question, I cant wait for the `makeMove` function because it even returns when the state variables are not changed.

`makeMove` will place the stone in the respective column.

`handleClick` function:

[image]

`makeMove` function:

[image]

2. Now I can't wait for the `useEffect()` of one variable because I need all three game variables to be changed. (If the bool changed but the grid is not updated -> error etc.)

EDIT: `useEffect()` hook picture and the vars:

[image]

Comment: `setState` can have a callback after execution, the problem is there are 3 setstate inside your handle click, it can be ugly nested but doable. But I'm afraid that this will guide you into some wrong ways. I believe your question is legit, probably you want to paste the code in `codeblock` in post instead of using image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply define your state as a single object? That way you can easily trigger a re-render when any one of your state variables changes.

Suppose you define your state like this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  grid: createGrid(),
  pTurn: true,
  gameState: 0
});
```

Then, lets say you want to update your state by setting the flag that the player turn has changed:

```
const {grid, pTurn, gameState} = state;
setState({grid, pTurn: !pTurn, gameState});
```

Updating state when `grid` or `gameState` changes should follow a similar pattern and I'm leaving that part out for brevity's sake.